# adding and removing stock from database

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to add back stock to my database when an item is removed from the shopping cart by the user. My 'reduce stock' route works just fine and I am able to remove stock from my database. I have tried to do the reverse and get some strange results. When I `req.body.productStock` it just returns the original stock of 1000 and "adds" 1 to it and it ends up as 10001. I would love any help.

reduce stock route and views which works just fine:

```
router.post('/add-to-cart/:id', function(req, res, next){
        var productId = req.params.id;
        var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});
        var size = req.body.bikeSize 
        var reduceStock = req.body.productStock - 1;   <----
        var newData = {productStock: reduceStock} <----
        Product.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, newData, function(err, product){ <----
            if(err){
                // !!!!add an error message!!!!
                return res.redirect('/');
            }
            console.log(reduceStock) <----

            cart.add(product, product.id, size);
            req.session.cart = cart;
            console.log(req.session.cart);
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
```

The ejs where I am 'adding the item to my cart, therefore reducing the stock'

```
<form action="/add-to-cart/<%= bike.id %>" method="POST">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="addToCart">Add to Cart</button>
        <select name="bikeSize" class="custom-select" id="" aria-label="">
            <% var sizes = bike.sizes %>                         
            <% sizes.forEach(function(bikeSize) { %> 
            <option name="bikeSize" value="<%= bikeSize.size %>"> <%= bikeSize.size %> </option>
            <% }); %>
            <input type="text" value="<%= bike.productStock %>" name="productStock" hidden>
            </select>
      </form>
```

**my add stock route and views which does not work:**

```
   router.post('/reduce/:id', function(req, res, next){
        var productId = req.params.id;
        var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});
        var size = req.body.bikeSize 
        var addStock = req.body.productStock + 1;  <----
        var newData = {productStock: addStock} <----
        Product.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, newData, function(err, product){ <----
            if(err){
                // !!!!add an error message!!!!
                console.log(err);
                return res.redirect('/');

            }
        console.log(addStock) <----
        cart.reduceByOne(productId);
        req.session.cart = cart;
        res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
    });

});
```

**here is the ejs where I am 'deleting from my cart, therefore adding stock back to the db'**

```
<form action="/reduce/<%= product.item._id %>" method="POST">
       <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="addToCart">Reduce by 1</button>
       <input type="text" value="<%= product.item.productStock %>" name="productStock" hidden>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `$inc` operator?

Answer (score 0):

It must be that `bike.productStock` is an int datatype and `product.item.productStock` is a string.

Please look into this direction.